# Avoid false wake-ups in conditional variable notifying unknown number of threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, wakeup

I am using conditional variables to notify an unknown number of threads periodically.
i.e. a loop will periodically modify a value and then notify all threads waiting on the variable.
The usual method to avoid false wake-ups is to use a boolean variable.

The thread waiting on the variable after waking up, sets the value of the `bool` to `false`

```
class foo
{
    std::mutex mtx;
    std::condition_variable cv;
    bool update;
    public:

    void loop()
    {
        std::this_thread::seep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
            update = true;
        }
        cv.notify_all();
    }

    void wait()
    {
        while(!update)
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
            cv.wait();
            if(update)
            {
                update = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

};
```

The function `foo::loop` is started in a thread, and other threads that do periodic procedures will wait via the function `foo::wait`.

But since the different threads may start waiting at different times, it would seem that each thread would require a dedicated boolean variable to ensure no false wake-ups.

Since I don't know how many threads may wait on it, i cant use arrays of bool or anything.

So is there any method other than using a `std::map<std::thread::id,bool>` for tracking all updates.

Comment: update and updated are two different things?

Comment: @Surt Oh, sorry, no it isn't, they are both same, it was a typo it has been corrected.

Comment: Why don't you use `notify_one`? One waiter thread sets `update` to `false`, so all the other ones will be suspended immediately after woken up.

Comment: @geza I want all threads to get the update, so if one sets the update to false, all threads will block further.

Comment: That's why I'm asking. Why do you wake all threads, if you send all but one to sleep afterwards? It's a waste of resources, if your worker threads runs the same code. If they run a different code, then you should create separate cv for each kind of worker thread.

Comment: If you do want to wake all up (it means that all of threads has some work to, not just one), then yes, you'll need a separate `update` variable for each thread.

Comment: @geza yes, each thread needs to be woken for whatever work it does, so if it needs a separate update variable for each thread, should i proceed with a `std::map` or is there any other easier way

Comment: I depends on what you want to achieve exactly. `std::map` seems a little bit of overkill for this problem, a simple array/vector should be sufficient, as you can give each thread an index. Or you can go with Balazs's answer, if that fits your need. I recommend you to some material about conditional variables. The CV's condition's (in your case `update`) purpose is not just to handle "false" wakeups (do you mean spurious wakeup here?). It is needed as well, when your worker thread still runs, when the CV signalled, to avoid "missing" a condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using a cycle counter, you can make sure that all threads wake up on the notify, and there are no false wake-ups. The only issue is the possibility of the cycle counter overflowing.

Note: I also moved the `cv.wait()` predicate into a lambda.

```
class foo
{
    std::mutex mtx;
    std::condition_variable cv;
    int cycle_count = 0;
    public:

    void loop()
    {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
            ++cycle_count;
        }
        cv.notify_all();
    }

    void wait()
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
        int expected_cycle = cycle_count + 1;
        cv.wait(lock, [expected_cycle](){ return cycle_count >= expected_cycle; });
    }

};
```

If it's okay that the controller thread waits for all workers before initiating an update, the cycle counter can be exchanged with a bool that's flipped back and forth, thus avoiding the overflow issue.

```
class foo
{
    std::mutex mtx;
    std::condition_variable cv;
    bool is_cycle_count_even = true;
    int threads_waiting;
    int threads_to_notify;
    public:

    void loop()
    {
        while (true) {
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
            if (threads_to_notify == 0) { break; }
        }

        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
            threads_to_notify = threads_waiting;
            threads_waiting = 0;
            is_cycle_count_even ^= true;
        }
        cv.notify_all();
    }

    void wait()
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
        ++threads_waiting;
        bool expected_cycle = !is_cycle_count_even;
        cv.wait(lock, [expected_cycle](){ return is_cycle_count_even == expected_cycle; });
        --threads_to_notify;
    }

};
```

This way, worker threads that enter `wait()` after the controller has already started notifying (or at least acquired the mutex before the notify) will only get notified in the next cycle.